# Spring Security doesn't intercept request

Tags: java, spring, security

Hy guys. I'm new in Spring Security and I wanna make a simple application to test Spring Security. The problem is that simple configuration doesn't work and spring doesn't deny requests. I have the following configuration

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Class configuration:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("daimon4").password("123123")
                .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().denyAll();
    }
}
```

And I can still go to any page.
Can you help me? please. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't look like you have Spring Boot configured. Do you?

Comment: No, I use Tomcat.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You have added code that relies on Spring Boot autoconfiguration, whether standalone or running [in a servlet container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html). Follow the Spring guides _fully_ - skip no steps.

Comment: Ok, I'm new in that, what should I do to run in on Tomcat? change configuration or what?)

Comment: Follow the Spring guides _fully_ - skip no steps. See my link above.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks)